# JavaScript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string error jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some problem with my jQuery code. I've got this code:

```
$(document).ready({
  $('#es').click(function(){
    console.log("hola");
  });
})
```

And this output:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string 
>   Blockquote

In this line:

> $('#es').click(function()

I read other posts but they couldn't help me. Any solution?

Comment: The method `ready` expects a method as the first param, you're passing an object. This will never work. Have you read the jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for `ready`? It has some good examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) (and any other examples you may have seen) more carefully. `.ready()` expects a function as the first argument, but you are providing an object instead. The documentation says:

> The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function:
>
> $( document ).ready(**function()** {
>
> // Handler for .ready() called.
>
> });

Using your code it would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#es').click(function(){
    console.log("hola");
  });
});
```

Or you could use the shorthand version:

```
$(function() {
  $('#es').click(function(){
    console.log("hola");
  });
});
```

N.B.It needs to be given a function, so that it can save that function for later, and then execute it when the page is ready. This type of saved-for-later function reference is often referred to as a "callback" function.

Comment: ok great. They should both work, btw, but yes the second one is quicker to write :-)